# Change color Navigation Div when it passed from specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the color from white to black and/or black to white of my navbar-toggle.

But the problem is when it reach a sepecific div with a specific class like 'white' or 'black' the color changes when the scroll begins.

```
var stickyOffset = $(".navbar-toggle").offset();
var $contentDivs = $("section");
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $contentDivs.each(function(k) {
       var _thisOffset = $(this).offset();
       var _actPosition = _thisOffset.top - $(window).scrollTop();
       if (_actPosition < (stickyOffset.top + $('.navbar-toggle').height()/2) && _actPosition + $(this).height() - $('.navbar-toggle').height()/2 > 0) {
          $(".bar1, .bar2, .bar3, .navbar-span").removeClass("white black").addClass($(this).hasClass("white") ? "white" : "black");
       }
    });
});
```

Now my jsfiddle but it changes very fast and I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/xarlyblack/8mn4bucw/

Thank you in advance!
Best,
Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if I understand correctly your problem, but it seems to me that you have a logic error with your color label assignment, I think it should be like this:

```
...
if (_actPosition < (stickyOffset.top + $('.navbar-toggle').height()/2) &&
    _actPosition + $(this).height() - $('.navbar-toggle').height()/2 > 0) {
          $(".bar1, .bar2, .bar3, .navbar-span").removeClass("white black")
          .addClass($(this).hasClass("white") ? "black" : "white");
}
...
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ghasd39v/) is an updated jsfiddle in which I think it is properly working

Comment: Wow Thank you so much for your answer and you understand perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, in your jsfiddle the two classes should be switched, but if i understand you correctly, on initial page load the classes also do not match if you, for example already scrolled down and make a page reload/refresh or you come from a anchor link.

To fix this i would suggest you also run the class-switch after document load like this:

```
var stickyOffset = $(".navbar-toggle").offset();
var $contentDivs = $("section");
$(document).scroll(function() {
    checkcolor();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    checkcolor();
});

function checkcolor()
{
    $contentDivs.each(function(k) {
        var _thisOffset = $(this).offset();
        var _actPosition = _thisOffset.top - $(window).scrollTop();
        if (_actPosition < (30 + $('.navbar-toggle').height()/2) && _actPosition + $(this).height() - $('.navbar-toggle').height()/2 > 0) {
            $(".bar1, .bar2, .bar3, .navbar-span").removeClass("white black").addClass($(this).hasClass("white") ? "black" : "white");
        }
    });

}
```

I added a function call on document ready, and removed your stickyOffset Variable, because on page reload/refresh you are positioned in the middle of the site, the offset is way of. Your stickyOffset needs to be a fixed value. I just added the default number of 30 in.

See a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5gcemfz0/3/

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is in

```
$(".bar1, .bar2, .bar3, .navbar-span").removeClass("white black").addClass($(this).hasClass("white") ? "white" : "black");
```

that place. It says that 'if $(this) has class 'white' add 'white' else add 'black'. Should change places. Hope it helps!

Comment: I know it but I don't know exactly where is, thank you so much for the answer :)